# Multi user app login with Touch ID on iPad

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, touch-id

Im looking into creating an iPad kiosk app to be used by multiple staff in store.

I understand that IOS8 exposes Touch ID to apps - my question is, is it possible to use Touch ID to authenticate AND identify multiple users logging into an app?

Not that it should matter too much but the app will be Hybrid/Cordova.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not identify user, you can only authenticate a user.

Comment: This is correct. Please submit a Radar bug on this.