# Using Touch ID not for login

Tags: ios, ios9, touch-id

Is it possible to use the Touch ID sensor in an app but not for login authentication? In the app, a user can scan another person's finger. The fingerprint will then be matched against the database finding that person's profile.

Comment: iOS (and the apps) don't have access to the *contents* of Touch ID. Even Apple can't access it, it's all compartmentalized. So I *suppose* the answer is no.

Comment: i know it wasn't in the past, I don't know if it became possible in ios9, I am guessing not..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi user app login with Touch ID on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695669/multi-user-app-login-with-touch-id-on-ipad)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is no. Reference: https://www.noknok.com/what-they-say/blog/apple-touch-id-app-for-mobile-fingerprint-authentication

> So, is Apple’s Touch ID API the answer to our online authentication
>   needs? Currently, the API provides only two capabilities:
>
> 1. The ability to determine if the user was successfully authenticated to the device using the fingerprint sensor.
> 2. The ability to unlock iOS keychain data with successful fingerprint authentication.
>
> While both capabilities offer local authentication, they do not
>   provide a mechanism for the application or the user to authenticate to
>   a remote server. App developers looking to implement remote
>   authentication must create their own solution.

However, you could do as follows:

> One mechanism to accomplish remote authentication is by using the
>   Touch ID Keychain API to store passwords. A successful fingerprint
>   authentication will unlock the password, allowing the app to use the
>   password to authenticate to the server on behalf of the user. While
>   quick and simple, this method still retains many of the legacy
>   security problems of passwords including the vulnerability to large
>   scale server side attacks on password databases. The user also bears
>   the burden of keeping passwords in sync between the iOS keychain and
>   the server, raising the possibility of significant user confusion and
>   friction.